# fast and efficient pagination in mongodb using express and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

I have a collection with name product in mongodb, I have more then 2 million products in it. I just want to paginate from first document to last, no filter, no sorting is needed.

I use skip() and limit() but response time is exponential as skip() value gets bigger.

````
app.get('/products', async (req, res) => {
try {
        var query = isNaN(req.query.page) ? 0 : req.query.page <= 0 ? 0 : parseInt(req.query.page) || 0;
        const productPerPage = 20;
        var totalPages = Product.countDocument();
        totalPages = Math.floor(totalPages / 20);
        query = query > totalPages ? totalPages : query;
        const data = await Product.find()
        .sort({_id:1})
        .skip(query * productPerPage)
        .limit(productPerPage)
        res.status(200).render('products', { data, currPage:query, totalPages});
        } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
        }
} ```


its working proper but when the database gets larger the response time gets greater.
````

Answer (score 0):

Using skip and limit to paginate means that the db server needs to load the matching documents, sort them, then apply the skip and limit.

Using the sort on `{_id:1}` will allow the server to read the _id values from the index in pre-sorted order instead of an in-memory sort, but it will still need to scan all of the values in order to find the first one to return, i.e., on the first call it will start at the first document and return 20, on the second call it will read 40 documents, discard the first 20 and return 20, etc. so on the last call it will read all 2 million documents and discard 1,999,980 of them.  This is why it is so much slower on the later pages.

There are alternate pagination methods that perform better.  For example, instead of requesting just a page number, if the application were to include the previous _id value in the request, the route could query for `Product.find({_id:{$gt: ObjectId(req.query.lastseen)}}).sort({_id:1}).limit(productPerPage)` which would both have a more predictable runtime, and would not suffer from missing documents if one were deleted between calls.

Comment: yeah but this approach restrict user to jump random pages, for example if a user wanna goto page 100 he/she has to go through all the previous pages (1 to 99 page).

Comment: If you need to support jumping to an arbitrary location without criteria, collection scan is probably the only way to go.